Preventing Screenflashing when moving back to Origin in an Endless Runner Java Game
I am developing a 3D endless runner game in Java. As endless runners continue to run in a single direction infinitely, I move my obstacles and paths (the floor) back to the origin (starting from 0,0,0) after the player walks the span of 9 paths. That way, the Z coord (Depth coordinate) does not reach an absurdly huge number the longer the game goes on.
However, when I do move everything, there is a short flash on the screen making it obvious that the move happened. How could I prevent this flash? I was thinking of making a copy of the current onscreen objects and paths and moving those first, then the player (and camera), and then deleting the previous paths and objects, but I don't think adding and deleting stuff is a good idea.
5 sec youtube video of flash
Here is my code:
//if player pos is further than 9 paths, reset everything back to default (0, 0, 0) pos
if(player.getZ() >= PATHWAY_LENGTH * pathways.get(0).getDepth())  { //it does not matter which pathway we get the depth from

      for(int i = 0; i < PATHWAY_LENGTH; i++) {
           pathways.get(i).getInstance().transform.setTranslation(0, 0, i * pathways.get(i).getDepth());
      }
                
      for(Obstacle obstacle : activeObjects) {
          obstacle.getInstance().transform.setTranslation(obstacle.getX(), obstacle.getY(), obstacle.getAssociatedPath().getZ());
      }
                
      player.getInstance().transform.setTranslation(player.getX(), player.getY(), 0f);
      System.out.println("Relocated back to origin");
}

Note (incase this is important): I am using libGDX (for 3D models), .setTranslation is one of its default methods of modelInstances
I would appreciate suggestions on what to do, and can provide additional code if necessary. Thank you!

I can't tell what exactly is causing the flash but I'd suspect the translation might not be happening between 2 frames, i.e. world update and rendering are independent - which normally is good except in cases like these. Maybe a fundamentally different approach might work here: instead of moving the player through the world move the world around the player (means: the player always stays at the origin).

I haven't used the 3d parts of libgdx before, but are there any options around double buffering you could look into?
